# What are `*.userosscache` files generated by Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, gitignore

They're mentioned in `.gitignore` template for Visual Studio, provided by GitHub:
https://github.com/github/gitignore/blame/d0b80a46/VisualStudio.gitignore#L10

But I couldn't google anything intelligible on this extension. The only idea I have is that "oss" here means "Object Storage Service".

What are these files, what are they for, and what creates them (maybe some VS plugin)?

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the [8 years-old commit](https://github.com/github/gitignore/commit/fdde4a04d3f8a018ad45f2f0738ee8f71f6a87c1) which introduced that file:

> I haven't found good documentation for this file online, but it is a user based file that should be ignored.

Since the OP reports OSS is "Object Storage Service", this could be a file generated by GitLab and its "[Consolidated object storage configuration](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/object_storage.html)" support.
When integrated with Visual Studio, such a service might leave some local file for caching.

Comment: Yep, I noticed this as well, and that's why I've been asking this question. :)

Comment: @DmitryD.Chernov The point is: from this commit comment, there is no definitive documentation for that user-generated file.